# How do you calculate IoU when there are multiple faces in frame?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, face-detection

I'm trying to evaluate some face detection algorithms by calculating the mAP. I'm trying to calculate the IoU between the bounding boxes, but I'm running into a problem when the frame has multiple faces.

For example, lets say I have 3 ground truth bounding boxes for 3 faces. How do I know which generated bounding box matches with which ground truth bounding box? Furthermore, how can I factor in when the algorithm detects more OR less faces than ground truth?